# Weird bug in table

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-tables

I have a table with 2 rows and 6 colums.

I was playing in `inspect element` and came with the solution I needed ( see picture below )

[image]

as you see it looks good now.

Once I applied it into the css of the website It looks like below:

[image]

**CSS**

```
style1 //Categorie
{
    width:175px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.style2
{
width: 175px; //Klant
}

.style3
{
    width:175px; // Website
}

.style4
{
    width:175px; // Titel
}
```

The code I entered was for the 1st tbl row( the dropdown `Categorie` ) to `display:inline-block`

Anyone has a clue how to result could be different?

I need to get "Klant" to the left, near "Categorie"

Comment: some css and html would help a lot

Comment: @LucPrevoo i was updating while asking haha not much css, just the widths applied

Comment: definitely need the html and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful

Comment: What effect/look are you trying to get?

Comment: I need to get "Klant" to the left, near "Categorie"

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the display tag and add a float: left to all style blocks
Also: You missed a point before style1

```
.style1 //Categorie
{
    width:175px;
    float: left;
}

.style2
{
width: 175px; //Klant
float: left;
}

.style3
{
    width:175px; // Website
    float: left;
}

.style4
{
    width:175px; // Titel
    float: left;
}
```

If that does not work, please post the html

Comment: ... and to optimize a bit since it's all the same css declarations over and over, why not just `.style{ width:175px; float:left; } `- one class to fit them all.

Comment: Combined these 2. not sure why I couldnt think of that. Maybe I was to focused on styling the mseperated

Comment: perhaps same as `.style1, .style2, .style3, .style4 { width:175px; float: left;
}`

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots, the only difference appears to be that the table is wider in the second one:

[image]

Is that what you're trying to resolve?

I suspect that your issue is simply that the table is flowing into a wider area (thus the columns are wider, and everything within the table falls further apart).  Is it possible that the classes you've posted are assigned to the selects rather than to the table cells?

Best bet is to assign a width to the table if that's the case - you can do this by giving the table a class ans assigning the width in there, or directly into the table mark up itself (less-recommended).

Comment: Thats correct I need to get "Klant" to the left, near "Categorie"

Comment: Great! In that I fully suspect that the the reason it's spread out further is that the table itself is inheriting a wider width.  
  
Here's what I would suggest:  
* Remove the CSS you're using the try and force the column widths  
* Instead add a class to the table itself and set it's width.